# SharePoint Quick Launch not opening

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I want to edit a link on the left side of a SharePoint 2013 Standard site. Clicking on Edit Links and changing the link to a desired site and then saving shows error "This operation has timed out. Please try again." and clicking on Quick launch keeps spinning. I have full access to the site.

What could be the cause ?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

did You consider using PowerShell as a workaround solution? If something in SharePoint that is OOB and does not work I always consider PS to fix something :). 
For Your case something like this may do the trick (example to delete and update):

```
    if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) 
    {
        Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
    }

    $SPWeb = Get-SPWeb "[URL]";
    $QuickLaunch = $SPWeb.Navigation.QuickLaunch;
    foreach($item in $QuickLaunch)
    {
        $item.Title;
        if($item.Title -eq '[quickLunchItemTitleToDelete]')
        {
            $SPWeb.Navigation.GetNodeById($item.Id).Delete();
        }
        if($item.Title -eq '[quickLunchItemTitleToModify]')
        {
             $item.Title = "[NewName]";
             $item.Update();
        }
    }
```

also I saw You have in site settings link to Quick Lunch. But You may turn on a feature in web to get the more advanced 'Navigation' link and maybe from there You will be able to modify the link You need.

1. Go to Site settings > Under Site collection admin > Site collection
   features
2. Click Activate in-front of SharePoint Server Publishing
   Infrastructure

BUT please be aware that turning on this feature will add also other components to Your which may be not desired.

I hope this will be of any help to You :)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Event with power shell it got stuck at $SPWeb.Navigation.QuickLaunch step and script just keep waiting there. Anything else I can try ?

Comment: Really strange. For now I don't have any idea. Was this site created by some backup restore? Did You have any other issue with this site?